# Checkbox and file tags don't work in Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, file, angular, checkbox

I have a form in Angular2 with several input types: text, file, checkbox, and textarea. When you click on the text and textareas, they focus as expected. However, when I click on the checkbox or file elements, *nothing happens*. The checkbox doesn't check, the "select a file" dialog doesn't open. I've tried this with and without [ngModel] and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

At first I thought this might be because of some issue with z-index, but I've tried removing all instances of z-index and that doesn't make a difference.

Another thought I've had from researching this is that some method is getting called somewhere for these elements onclick that counteracts the natural behavior of the elements, but I can't find any instances of where this might be happening in my own code.

I am a beginner in Angular2 so apologies beforehand if it's some simple answer I haven't thought of.

TYIA!

Comment: [ngModel]? did you mean [(ngModel)]

Comment: post some of your code like the form elements that the problem occurs and any other relevant part

Comment: Can you provide a plunker that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 0):

While trying to simplify my app for plunkr, I found my problem. I have a directive "clickOutside" with a host listener on document:click to check if any a click is outside of an element or not. I have it used in a couple of places on the page. Turns out that if there is anything more than a simple method call inside it (e.g. (clickOutside)="runMethod(); otherValue = true;" as opposed to (clickOutside)="runMethod() it makes the file and checkbox tags not work correctly. I don't know why it does this, but it makes for an easy fix!